# non-webkit browsers ignore @media queries with webkit-specific features

Tags: css, webkit, media-queries

I'm trying to pass the following @media query, but it's ignored in all non-webkit browsers:

```
@media not all and (-webkit-transform-2d) and (-webkit-transform-3d) and (-webkit-transform) {[...]}
```

What I expect to happen is that all webkit browsers that do not return true to all three features are passed, which is also what happens.

Likewise, based on [Safari documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/OtherStandardCSS3Features.html) on @media queries, I expect all non-webkit browsers to return false on all three features since they don't support them, but the @media query is ignored instead.

I had a look at the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#error-handling), but I'm not sure how to interpret it correctly.

Can someone help me find the error or another way to style elements in browsers that do not return true in the query?

I'm not interested in JavaScript solutions.

Thank you.

Incidentally, vendor-specific @viewport queries were also ignored for some reason.

Comment: This shouldn't surprising, non-webkit browsers will not understand webkit specific properties... These are experimental properties, you need to use all vendor prefixes for full support. And yes, that does suck.

Comment: That's what I suspected. I thought I read in the documentation that unsupported features would return false though, but I guess that's not true. So does this mean there are equivalents for each vendor, like `-moz-transform-3d`?

Comment: you should sort appart rules for webkit and others , you could use the @support rule to overwrite your defaut rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, instead use the conditionnal rules  `@support`: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#at-supports

Comment: How widely is this rule supported? It sounds like a perfect solution, way better than what I had hoped for, but it doesn't look like it's been implemented in all major browsers yet. I don't want to get stuck in an infinite loop trying to do `@supports (@supports (@supports (...` :P

Comment: Never mind, I found a comprehensive list of browsers that have implemented the feature [here](http://caniuse.com/css-featurequeries). I'm gonna go with this for now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Actually, what matters is to know if webkit supports it, since you check on it to serve it specific webkit rules  see http://caniuse.com/#search=@support (safari out apparently)

Comment: Yes, but I would need a `@supports (not ([...])) {[...]}` for browsers that don't. Otherwise, the browsers that do support the rule would get styled twice, if I added style outside a @supports rule as well in order to account for the browser that do not support it.

Comment: if you use prefix webkit , no other browser than webkit will respond, no need to check on not :) , and if needed , restore here defaut value of rules you want to drop

Comment: What do you mean "...restore default value of rules you want to drop"?

Say I have two styles, A and B. I want A for browsers that support A and B for browsers that don't. If @supports only works in webkit, then how would I apply B to other browsers without also applying it when I apply A?

Comment: for instance :A has `{transform: rotate() ...; margin: 3em;}`   B can kill all sort of transform  with `transform:scale(1);` then `margin:auto` or `0`. `@support`, B, rules needs to be called later.

Comment: That's true, but then I would have to negate or alter all A's values  that I don't want in B. It works though :) Anyway, thanks for the help. :)